# ASP.net MVC HTTP Request error with payload

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, http

I am creating an ASP.net MVC website with a RESTful API to a SQL database. I have implemented a controller which holds the HTTP commands.

One of the commands is a `POST`command:

```
     // POST: api/PoolTests
     [ResponseType(typeof(PoolTest))]
     public IHttpActionResult PostPoolTest(PoolTest poolTest)
     {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.PoolTests.Add(poolTest);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = poolTest.Id }, poolTest);
     }
```

I am using Fiddler to test out the function and I am getting some strange results. According to the automatically generated API documents the request format should be JSON with this structure (These are the fields to the connect SQL database):

```
               {
                 "Id": 1,
                 "SiteID": "sample string 2",
                 "Date": "sample string 3",
                 "Tub": "sample string 4",
                 "par1": 5.1,
                 "par2": 6.1,
                 "par3": 7.1,
                 "par4": 8.1
               }
```

In the fiddler composer I select `POST` and `http://localhost:53660/api/PoolTests` and the JSON payload `{"Id": 1,"SiteID": "sample string 2",   "Date": "sample string 3","Tub": "sample string 4","par1": 5.1, "par2": 6.1,"par3": 7.1,"par4": 8.1}`

This results in a HTTP 400 error code.

If I send the same request with no JSON (payload) then it breaks at the line `db.PoolTests.Add(poolTest);` because the payload is null.

With payload if I place a break point at line `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` the breakpoint is never reached. It is almost like with payload the actual HTTP command is not being recognised.

Any thoughts - I appreciate that there may be some details missing.

ADDED: PoolTest Class

```
public class PoolTest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SiteID { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Tub { get; set; }
    public double par1 { get; set; }
    public double par2 { get; set; }
    public double par3 { get; set; }
    public double par4 { get; set; }
}
```

FIDDLER Screenshot Added:

I have added the `content-type` and now I hit the breakpoint, but the `Pooltest` is reported as being `null`

[image]

Comment: Could you post your PoolTest class? Does it have validation rules on it to enforce?

Comment: @br4d - added the PoolTest class

Comment: Your request must have header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Please check if you have this header or not.

Comment: @alisabzevari - I have added the content-type as you have suggested. The breakpoint is now hit, however, `pooltest` is reported as being `null`. I have added a screenshot of my fiddler request which may contain errors around `data`.

Comment: Now I think [FromBody] will work!

Comment: It does! But why is the `poolTest` a `null`?

Comment: Can you write a simple code that send an ajax request? If so, and worked, you can then compare with the request you have sent with Fiddler. And IMHO Postman is better than fiddler.

Comment: @alisabzevari - is there an equivalent to fiddler/postman for ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `data` to the Request Body. In Fiddler it would be a separate input box (below the one in your screenshot).

Your **Headers** for `POST http://localhost:53660/api/pooltests` become:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:53660
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 140
```

The headers `Content-Type` should be *application/json* and the `Content-Length` will be computed for you. You are defining a header `data` which isn't correct.

In the **Request Body** you can paste your data

```
{"Id": 1,"SiteID": "sample string 2",   "Date": "sample string 3","Tub": "sample string 4","par1": 5.1, "par2": 6.1,"par3": 7.1,"par4": 8.1}
```

You can leave your action signature alone but `[FromBody]` is helpful when you want to add parameters to the URL.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(PoolTest))]
public IHttpActionResult PostPoolTest([FromBody] PoolTest poolTest)
{
    ...
}
```

An AJAX request with jQuery would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:53660/api/pooltests",
    method: "POST",
    data: { "Id": 1, "SiteID": "sample string 2", "Date": "sample string 3", "Tub": "sample string 4",
            "par1": 5.1, "par2": 6.1, "par3": 7.1, "par4": 8.1 }
})
.done(function(result) {
    console.log("success", result);
})
.fail(function(xhr, txtStatus) {
    console.log("error", txtStatus);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that the **Request Body** was not displaying the way I had fiddler docked. Secondly, I was neglecting the `content-length`. Both these resulted in the Request Body data being received. Although I now I have a slight dilemma - another question!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your method signature to:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostPoolTest([FromBody]PoolTest poolTest)
```

This should allow you to at least hit your breakpoint. From there you can see model errors.

Comment: Did you get it figured out?